# PHP Consolidate / Merge Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to consolidate the following json object into a single object but can't wrap my head around a way to do this.

Current JSON:

```
{
    "id": "a57c57a5c1d6581cf5b9fff6737827ce",
    "sport_key": "basketball_nba",
    "sport_title": "NBA",
    "commence_time": "2023-05-20T00:30:00Z",
    "home_team": "Boston Celtics",
    "away_team": "Miami Heat",
    "bookmakers": [
        {
            "key": "draftkings",
            "title": "DraftKings",
            "markets": [
                {
                    "key": "player_assists",
                    "last_update": "2023-05-18T18:58:05Z",
                    "outcomes": [
                        {
                            "name": "Over",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": -130,
                            "point": 2.5
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Under",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": 100,
                            "point": 2.5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "player_points",
                    "last_update": "2023-05-18T18:58:05Z",
                    "outcomes": [
                        {
                            "name": "Over",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": -115,
                            "point": 7.5
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Under",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": -115,
                            "point": 7.5
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "fanduel",
            "title": "FanDuel",
            "markets": [
                {
                    "key": "player_assists",
                    "last_update": "2023-05-18T18:57:22Z",
                    "outcomes": [
                        {
                            "name": "Over",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": -128,
                            "point": 2.5
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Under",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": 100,
                            "point": 2.5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "player_points",
                    "last_update": "2023-05-18T18:57:22Z",
                    "outcomes": [
                        {
                            "name": "Over",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": -111,
                            "point": 7.5
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Under",
                            "description": "Al Horford",
                            "price": -115,
                            "point": 7.5
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The above is broken down into separate `bookmakers`, ie **draftkings** and **fanduel** and then further down it's broken down into `markets`, ie **player_assists** and **player_points**

What I'm trying to do is consolidate it down into the following format where you have it broken down by `market`: (**player_assists** & **player_points**) and then also separated by whether it's for the `Over` or `Under`:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Al Horford",
    "key": "player_assists",
    "name": "Over",
    "draftkings_price": -130,
    "draftkings_point": 2.5, 
    "fanduel_price": -128,
    "fanduel_point": 2.5, 
  },
  {
    "description": "Al Horford",
    "key": "player_assists",
    "name": "Under",
    "draftkings_price": 100,
    "draftkings_point": 2.5, 
    "fanduel_price": 100,
    "fanduel_point": 2.5, 
  },
  {
    "description": "Al Horford",
    "key": "player_points",
    "name": "Over",
    "draftkings_price": -115,
    "draftkings_point": 7.5, 
    "fanduel_price": -111,
    "fanduel_point": 7.5, 
  },
  {
    "description": "Al Horford",
    "key": "player_points",
    "name": "Under",
    "draftkings_price": -115,
    "draftkings_point": 7.5, 
    "fanduel_price": -115,
    "fanduel_point": 7.5, 
  },
]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really wouldn't have keys like `draftkings_price` and `fanduel_price`. What happens if you add another bookmaker? Or you want another field for each bookmaker? Instead, I would do something like:

```json
"price": { "draftkings" : -115, "fanduel" : -111 }
```

It doesn't overly complicate getting a price:

```php
$data->price->draftkings
```

instead of

```php
$data->draftkings_price
```

and it makes it much easier to get all the price values:

```php
array_values(array($data->price))
```

instead of

```php
[$data->draftkings_price, $data->fanduel_price, ...]
```

Anyway, here's how you can group the price/point data and then output to a flattened array. It would be relatively easy to modify this code if you want to have `draftkings_price` type keys instead.

```php
$markets = array();

// group price, point by market name, description, outcome name
foreach ($data->bookmakers as $bookmaker) {
    $bm_name = $bookmaker->key;
    foreach ($bookmaker->markets as $market) {
        $mkt_name = $market->key;
        foreach ($market->outcomes as $outcome) {
            $key = implode('\n', [$mkt_name, $outcome->name, $outcome->description]);
            $markets[$key]['price'][$bm_name] = $outcome->price;
            $markets[$key]['point'][$bm_name] = $outcome->point;
        }
    }
}

// ungroup to flat object
$output = array();

foreach ($markets as $key => $value) {
    [$value['key'], $value['name'], $value['description']] = explode('\n', $key);
    $output[] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output for your sample data:

```json
[
    {
        "price": {
            "draftkings": -130,
            "fanduel": -128
        },
        "point": {
            "draftkings": 2.5,
            "fanduel": 2.5
        },
        "key": "player_assists",
        "name": "Over",
        "description": "Al Horford"
    },
    {
        "price": {
            "draftkings": 100,
            "fanduel": 100
        },
        "point": {
            "draftkings": 2.5,
            "fanduel": 2.5
        },
        "key": "player_assists",
        "name": "Under",
        "description": "Al Horford"
    },
    {
        "price": {
            "draftkings": -115,
            "fanduel": -111
        },
        "point": {
            "draftkings": 7.5,
            "fanduel": 7.5
        },
        "key": "player_points",
        "name": "Over",
        "description": "Al Horford"
    },
    {
        "price": {
            "draftkings": -115,
            "fanduel": -115
        },
        "point": {
            "draftkings": 7.5,
            "fanduel": 7.5
        },
        "key": "player_points",
        "name": "Under",
        "description": "Al Horford"
    }
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kfdie)

Comment: That makes perfect sense with the keys. Only reason I had it that way is that's how the API that I'm consuming outputs those values. But yeah this is perfect, thank you!